# Elasticsearch last indexed date using java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am currently working on Elasticsearch, I am querying Elasticsearch indexes using the NativeSearchQueryBuilder. We index the records on every alternate day. is there any way i can findout the last index date i.e the date on which each indexing is done.

Comment: curl -XGET localhost:port/test will return result will have created date of the index

Answer (score 0):

The creation date is in the settings of the index.

You can easily get the settings for an index by querying the [get settings api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-settings.html) like this:

`curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index/_settings`

```
{  
   "my_index":{  
      "settings":{  
         "index":{  
            "number_of_shards":"1",
            "provided_name":"my_index",
            "creation_date":"1507805145855",
            "number_of_replicas":"2",
            "uuid":"WYaah8swdD6pZOxes_4bgQ",
            "version":{  
               "created":"5060299"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see the `creation_date` is what you are looking for.